# react-native-image-picker is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have installed the package react-native-image picker:

```
npm i react-native-image-picker --save
```

And I have also linked it to my project:

```
react-native link react-native-image-picker
```

And when I try to import the module and use it:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

 ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
     // code here
   }
```

I receive this following error:

```
typeError: Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of undefined
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the solution for it,

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

const changePhoto = () => {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
    };
    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };


<TouchableOpacity onPress={changePhoto}>
     <Text>Change Photo</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should carefully check the newest documentation of this npm package as it was migrated to newer version. The old 2.x.x version is deprecated, as written in the [GitHub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) page of the package, thus names of key modules might have changed...

Answer (score 1):

At the place of

```js
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
```

replace with

```js
var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');
```

and run the application again.

Comment: You saved me! I had this problem in react native 66 and now it is working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For 3.x version, you can directly import the function like

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
```

In an Expo project, I still got the same error, like [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1146) (since `lauchImageLibrary` comes from `NativeModules.ImagePickerManager`). But it works fine in the project initialized with React Native CLI.

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.x, let run `npx pod-install` then get the function by that way `import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';`